# Как сделать активный слайд Swiper по текстовому анкору(якорю)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

Есть слайдер в Swiper состоящий из нескольких слайдов. У слайдера есть навигация по типу пагинации, только переключение по уменьшенным картинкам.

Можно ли при открытии страницы с текстовым анкором, например: site.ru/#slide1 отображать первый слайд при загрузке страницы, а при ссылке site.ru/#slide2 отображать второй слайд при загрузке страницы. И так же нажимая на элементы навигации, будем считать по пагинациям добавлять этот анкор в url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Автор **Swiper** видимо тоже подумал об этом и внёс такую возможность:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  // навигация по якорю 
  hashNavigation: true
})
```

Подробнее о [hashNavigation](https://swiperjs.com/api/#hash-navigation)